# Launching other application programmatically on WP7 - ideas

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a number of apps developed for WP7.
I'd like to launch one app from another.
I know the general answer is "no, you can't"

What if my app when launched for the first time registers at my server with a Device id and registers for push notifications?

Then when I want to launch app Foo from app Bar:

- app Bar pings my server with given Device id and application Foo id
- if server finds given Device has application Foo installed, it sends push-notification to the Foo app instance
- application Foo launches
- PROFIT!!!

What do you think about approach? Is it worth trying or better wait for Apollo which may bring us required changes? (or may not)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proposed approach isn't really going to work. If you're sending a raw notification from your server to the Foo application, and the application isn't running (it won't be), the MS servers will not deliver the notification to the phone, and your server will receive an error.

If you send a toast notification then, yes, the user will receive a toast to show something relating to the Foo application has occurred. They'll still have to tap the toast to launch the Foo application. That may be workable but seems a bit ... clunky.

Whilst there must be some mechanism for this (See YouTube and Acrobat applications) I'd say that, at present, it require special permissions / technical exemptions from the market place requirements. I think that you're very unlikely to receive these permissions / exemptions.

Comment: Just some extra info youtube and acrobat got their protocol / filetype registred in the shell what launches `app://[APPID]/_default?url=%s` :)