# Windows Phone 8 Application Record

Tags: windows-phone-7, nfc, windows-phone, windows-phone-8

Is there any way to reproduce on **Windows Phone 8** such thing like   **Android Application Record**?
Android Application Record -  NDEF record which tells phone to search for application from this record and if it is installed to launch it for processing NFC message, if such program is not installed on device then Play Store app is launched with search for this app [by package].

Comment: Not sure specifically about 8.  But see this SO thread for some thoughts.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9714111/launching-other-application-programmatically-on-wp7-ideas

Comment: This is in fact possible, for reference see the following answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13535811/1511136

Answer (score 0):

Launching arbitrary apps from an NFC tag isn't supported on WP8. Apps must opt-in to app2app custom protocols in-order to be launched from an NFC tag.

Any app that subscribes to an app2app custom protocol can be launched from that URI via an NFC tag with that URI custom protocol. There's nothing required to NFC-enable apps once they support custom protocols.

See instructions on how to implement app2app custom protocols @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206987(v=vs.105).aspx